# Lodash _forEach breaks typeguard in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript2.0, union-types

#### Background

Creating a variable `notifications` that I want to be false when I have no data, otherwise an array of objects. So I did a union type: `let notifications: object[] | boolean = [];` Fine except when I do `notifications.push(notification);` I got

```
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'boolean | object[]'.
  Property 'push' does not exist on type 'true'.
```

Right, TS isn't sure that it's an array. I'll let it know. `notifications = [];` Same error. Bunch more digging, realize the guard is working fine, it's only when I have my `.push` inside lodash's `_forEach` that I get the error.

Current state:

```
let notifications: object[] | boolean;

if (noNotifications) {
  notifications = false;
} else {
  notifications = [];
  _forEach(notificationsObj, function (notification, type) { // Culprit
    notification['type'] = type;
    notifications.push(notification); // <-- TS error on push
  });
}
return notifications;
```

#### What I've tried

A bunch of different ways of type guarding. Don't understand the reason `_forEach` is breaking it, so not sure what to try next.

#### Question

Is is possible to  use `push` on my variable inside `_forEach`? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't understand `_forEach` well enough to know that `notifications` will not be reassigned before it runs the code in the callback.  Since `notifications` is not `const`, TypeScript thinks it is *possible* for it to be reassigned.  There are many [tradeoffs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) in how TypeScript does its type-based control flow analysis; type narrowing propagating into closures is hard.  Since you can't really get TypeScript to follow the control flow, you have a few options:

---

The easiest is to just assert that `notifications` is an array when you do the `push()`:

```
_forEach(notificationsObj, function(notification, type) { // Culprit
  notification['type'] = type;
  (notifications as object[]).push(notification); // assertion
});
```

This assertion is you telling the compiler not to worry.

---

To get a more type safety at the expense of a little runtime assignment shuffling, introduce a `const` variable and then assign that to `notifications`:

```
const notificationsArray: object[] | boolean = []; // cannot be reassigned
_forEach(notificationsObj, function(notification, type) { // Culprit
  notification['type'] = type;
  notificationsArray.push(notification); // no error
});
notifications = notificationsArray; // assignment works
```

Here TypeScript knows that `notificationsArray` can never be reassigned, so its type stays narrowed `object[]` all the way into the callback.  Then you can assign its value to `notifications`.  (You could also just declare `notificationsArray` to just be type `object[]` and leave off `| boolean`.  I was just showing that `const` affects the narrowing.)

---

Hope you understand and that one of those solutions works for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

jcalz's answer addresses your specific question, but I just wanted to offer a different way of solving your problem. By writing it in a functional style, you can avoid a lot of these problems entirely.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

function getNotifications(notificationsObj: {[type: string]: object}): object[] | boolean {
  if (_.isEmpty(notificationsObj)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    // note: lodash map will turn an object into an array
    return _.map(notificationsObj, (notification, type) => {
      return {...notification, type};
    });
  }
}
```

Note I also avoid mutating the original notification objects, in contrast with your original solution. If you rely on that mutation taking place then you should change that part back.

Comment: Both the idea and the note about `map` are great to know. Upvoting this as well.